# Simplest way to return pid of nodejs child process

Tags: javascript, node.js

My script is meant to launch a python program from this nodejs script. (Nodejs is not my language).
I want to determine the pid of the python script after it is launched and then kill it any time i want. Here's my code.

```
var pid = {};

v1.on('write', function(param) {
    if (param[0] == '1') {
            child = exec('python /home/pi/startup/motion.py',
            function (error, stdout, stderr) {
                console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
                console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
                if (error !== null) {
                     console.log('exec error: ' + error);
                }
            });
        writeVal = 'motion sensor ON'; 
    }
    else if (param[0] == '0') {
        child = exec('kill'+ pid,
            function (error, stdout, stderr) {
                console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
                console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
                if (error !== null) {
                    console.log('exec error: ' + error);
                }
            });
        writeVal = 'Motion OFF';
    }
});
```

Comment: `child.pid` gives you the `pid`

Comment: @vibhor1997a so were exactly in do i put `chid.pid` ?

Answer (score 2):

[exec](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) returns a [ChildProcess](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_class_childprocess) object, so you can get the pid with `child.pid`.

You can also use `child.kill()` directly without using the shell command.

```
var child;

v1.on('write', function(param) {
    if (param[0] == '1') {
            child = exec('python /home/pi/startup/motion.py',
            function (error, stdout, stderr) {
                console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
                console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
                if (error !== null) {
                     console.log('exec error: ' + error);
                }
            });
        writeVal = 'motion sensor ON'; 
    }
    else if (param[0] == '0') {
        exec('kill '+ child.pid,
            function (error, stdout, stderr) {
                console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
                console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
                if (error !== null) {
                    console.log('exec error: ' + error);
                }
            });

        // 
        // child.kill()
        //

        writeVal = 'Motion OFF';
    }
});
```

Comment: what was the issue?

Comment: the script runs but then the parameter to kill the child process prints `stdout:
stderr:` to the console without actually killing the process.

Comment: do some investigation, print the pid, see if it's correct, see if `kill` works from the command line, see if `kill -9` works, see if `child.kill()` works...don't wait for others to fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have created a script for running python. I am assuming that you have PID with you. If you don't, once you run the python script, the `child` variable should give you PID with `child.pid`

Save it in `pid` variable. You can use the below command to kill the task.

`-f` is to ensure "Force kill"

Note: the space after /PID is mandatory to not get argument error

```
childProcess.exec('taskkill -f /PID ' + pid, function(err, stdout, stderr){
     var status = stdout.split(':')[0]
     if(status === 'SUCCESS'){ 
         //successfully killed
     } else if(status === 'ERROR'){
         //Ouch! PID does not exist
     }
     //Note: You get stdout for both the scenarios where PID is found and PID is not found                           
})
```

Comment: While this might be correct answer, it would be good if you could add some more detailed explanation - [from review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/25321154)

Comment: Hey! @VivekMehta, U10-Forward, thank you for the input. Keep up the support please :)